# Loop through "array" in batch file to shift elements

Tags: arrays, batch-file, for-loop, shift, delayedvariableexpansion

I have a batch file that is passed commands in the form of a string array from a Java file. The commands contain something like the following:

```
String[] commands = {"A", 
                     "B", 
                     "C", 
                     "C:\users\user\Documents",
                     "C:\users\user\Pictures"}
```

The commands array is dynamic, as it changes every time the java program is run. In the batch file, I create variables to take the values of the first three elements (A, B, and C in this case). Then I need to shift the directory strings to take up the first three elements of the array. Here is the batch code I have so far:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set /A paramCount=0
for %%x in (%*) do (
    set list[!paramCount!]=%%x
    set /A paramCount=paramCount+1
)
set argA=%list[0]%
set argB=%list[1]%
set argC=%list[2]%

set /A old=0
set /A new=!old!+3
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('set list[') do (
    echo old=!old!
    echo new=!new!
    set list[!old!]=!list[%new%]!
    echo !list[%old%]!
    set /A old=!old!+1
    set /A new=!new!+1 )
```

The problem I am having is with the line `set list[!old!]=!list[%new%]!`. As you can see, I have delayed expansion enabled. However, the !!'s are needed for the list[...] variable that is emulating an element in an array. However, I believe I need to use delayed expansion for "new" as well. What am I to do in this case? Or perhaps that's not the actual problem? The "old" and "new" variables are incrementing correctly, but the `echo !list[%old%]!` line returns the same value every time. I expect the same issue exists in that line, with "old"--It should have !'s surrounding it but the !'s are already being used for the list[...] variable. So what happens if you need nested !'s in a statement? Thanks for the aid!

Comment: In your code `%List[!new!]%` is always bigger or equal to 3 and the list you generate goes until `%List[2]%` so it canno't return a correct value. Can you explain what you're really want to do there is surely a simpliest way to go there.....

Comment: I'll do my best. I start with an "array" of sorts that contains three initial arguments, then an unknown number of further arguments (directories). I need to essentially use the first three arguments (set variables to their values), then remove them from the emulated array and shift all the directories so that only the directories remain in the emulated array. Does this make sense, or should I try to explain it further?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```dos
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set /A paramCount=-3
for %%x in (%*) do (
    set list[!paramCount!]=%%x
    set /A paramCount=paramCount+1
)
set argA=%list[-3]%
set argB=%list[-2]%
set argC=%list[-1]%
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('set list[-') do SET "%%a="
SET arg
SET list
ENDLOCAL
echo==================
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set /A paramCount=0
for %%x in (%*) do (
    set list[!paramCount!]=%%x
    set /A paramCount=paramCount+1
)
set argA=%list[0]%
set argB=%list[1]%
set argC=%list[2]%

set /A old=0
set /A new=!old!+3
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('set list[') do (
    echo old=!old!
    echo new=!new!
    CALL set list[%%old%%]=%%list[!new!]%%
    CALL ECHO(%%list[!old!]%%
    set /A old=!old!+1
    set /A new=!new!+1 
) 
SET arg
SET list
GOTO :EOF
```

This should work for you - the easy way and the hard way.

Comment: Are you sure about this line? 
    CALL ECHO(%%list[!old!]%%
Something does not seem quite right (missing parenthesis?). The %%list simply takes %%l as a variable, which of course doesn't work

Comment: Yes. It's a quirk of `ECHO` - the character directly following the `O` does some strange things. `ECHO(%var%` has been found to produce an empty line if `var` is empty, whereas `ECHO.%var%` would show the `ECHO` status (Echo is on/off). Looks odd - works a treat! (of course, in this instance, it's just a debug line you had...)

Comment: This works great, after a bit of tweaking. Thank you very much!